# How to avoid concurrency issues with EF 6.0 AddOrUpdate method?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

We have a CustomerInvoice table and a CustomerInvoiceDetails table. CustomerInvoiceDetails has CustomerInvoiceID as FK to CustomerInvoice Table.

We user rabbitMQ/NServiceBus to process Invoice messages. We use a TransactionScope with ReadUncommitted Isolation level to perform CustomerInvoice Upsert and then CustomerInvoiceDetail Update. However, we are running into a concurrency issue when we have multiple messages for the same Invoice.

For e.g. If we have 3 messages for the same invoice, we get three CustomerInvoice records instead of one since all messages are processed at the same time on different threads. The CustomerInvoiceDetails update happens correctly. We have a InvoiceNumber (column) which is generated thru code and is Unique for each Invoice. In this case, we get three invoices with the same InvoiceNumber, instead of one CustomerInvoice record.

`dbContext.CustomerInvoices.AddOrUpdate(x => x.InvoiceNumber, customerInvoice);`

We use `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` to save changes inside the transaction for CustomerInvoice Upsert.

We tried reading the CustomerInvoice before Insert, however all three messages read at the same time; a record does not exist and they are good to Insert.

How can we ensure that the Insert happens only once for each CustomerInvoice and the other two are rejected?